# LWJGL Cylinder Texture Mapping

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, texture-mapping

I wanted to know how to preform texture mapping on the org.lwjgl.util.glu.Cylinder class. I
want to be able to wrap the texture around the "Side/Curved" Part of the Cylinder.

This is my main question, but it would also be helpful to know how to preform this on all the 
"Quadric" classes in lwjgl.util.glu.

Answer (score 0):

according to the GL reference for `glUCylinder`:

> If texturing is turned on (with gluQuadricTexture), then texture 
>   coordinates are generated so that t ranges linearly from 0.0 
>   at z = 0 to 1.0 at z = height, and s 
>   ranges from 0.0 at the +y axis, to 0.25 at the +x axis, 
>   to 0.5 at the -y axis, to 0.75 at the -x axis, 
>   and back to 1.0 at the +y axis.

You can find references for the various OpenGL functions at the [OpenGL web site](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/).  They're for the C versions but the syntax doesn't change much for Java.

If that mapping isn't what you want, you will unfortunately have to write your own code to generate a cylinder model with the correct texture coordinates.